# May i use Firebase with half million records?

Tags: firebase

I'm planning to use Firebase.
but i heard that it is not fast enough.

I'm worried about the speed because I'm going to put 500,000 pieces of data.
Is it okay to use firebase ?

thanks.

Comment: 5 million doesn't look like a big number. As far as I know, firebase is designed to handle a lot more documents than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which Firebase product you're using (Realtime Database? Firestore?), but in either case, 500,000 is that that much.  With both products, as long as there are indexes created to make it possible to query your data at scale, it should be no problem.